# Copy map<double, tuple<double, double>> to map<double, double> without loop?

Tags: c++, dictionary, copy, tuples

I have a map of the form `map<double, tuple<double, double>> m1`. Can I copy this to a map of the form `map<double, double> m2` such that the keys are the same, and the value in m2 is `get<0>(m1->second)` *without using a loop*? Thanks!

Comment: Using `map<double,...>` is not recommended since any slight offset in the key value will give inconsistent results.

Comment: @MarkRansom perhaps he is using it for ordering. You can still use it to `find all keys > x` etc.

Comment: What I have is a map where the key is a number of years in the future, in decimal format. For example, 1.5 for 1.5 years from today. Could I run into problems with this kind of usage? Thanks.

Comment: And indeed the order is important for other functions I use on this map.

Comment: If your calculations will *always* deliver 1.5 and not 1.4999999999999999 or 1.5000000000000001 then you'll be fine. If you're not trying to find exact matches by key but are using `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, or `equal_range` then you can be OK with a little care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
vector<pair<double, double>> v(m1.size());
auto lambda = [](pair<double, tuple<double, double>> p){ return make_pair(p.first, get<0>(p.second)); };
transform(m1.begin(), m1.end(), v.begin(), lambda);
map<double, double> m2(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Note that we haven't really avoided a loop; we've just made `std::transform` do the looping for us. If even indirect looping isn't allowed, what you probably want is a transforming iterator. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html